# have a problem with swipe down to refresh

Tags: android

ive been trying to acomplish swipe down to refresh,what i wanna do is when i swipe down i want it to refresh the value in testviewsw1,but how ever whenever i try to do it, it doesnt even have the swipe thing. but have no idea why its just not working at all, ive already found some help from another website, but still got this error keep on showing up, really need help, its about my graduation project.please help me guys, really appreciate all helps form everyone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
            android:layout_width="393dp"
            android:layout_height="570dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.595" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="212dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.196"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingPrefix,ScrollViewSize">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/testviewSw1"
                    android:layout_width="128dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="燈泡1值"

                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.358"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.577"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/area_set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.951"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlCompat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/listenbutton2"
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/micro"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:onClick="listenButtonOnClick"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.835"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.842"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,OnClick" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
            android:layout_width="337dp"
            android:layout_height="187dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listenbutton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17"
            tools:ignore="UnknownIdInLayout" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="區域設置"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.03"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlCompat,UnknownId" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
            android:text="語音控制"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.732"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UnknownId,UnknownIdInLayout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="379dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#59fffac0"
            android:text="首頁"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
            android:text="Switch1:"
            android:textOff="OFF"
            android:textOn="ON"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.817"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.582"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    ----------


    ----------
     private String led;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home_main);
            // 下拉更新↓
            final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testviewSw1);

            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                    (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
                            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

below is my logcat

12-11 13:03:42.320 5420-5420/com.example.aaa.text E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
12-11 13:03:42.320 5420-5420/com.example.aaa.text E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-11 13:03:42.320 5420-5420/com.example.aaa.text E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.View.canScrollVertically(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.canChildScrollUp(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:678)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:701)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2108)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-11 13:03:42.320 5420-5420/com.example.aaa.text D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-11 13:03:42.321 5420-5420/com.example.aaa.text E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aaa.text, PID: 5420
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.View.canScrollVertically(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.canChildScrollUp(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:678)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:701)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2108)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

and below is my solutaion

final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        //抓 燈泡1值得layout
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testviewSw1);

```
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode actualObj = null;
            try {
                actualObj = mapper.readTree(led);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JsonNode ledObj = actualObj.get("led");
            int xx = ledObj.get("led17").asInt();
            System.out.println("led:" +  ledObj.get("led17"));
            if (xx == 1 ){

                tx1.setText("燈泡1:開");
            }
            else if (xx == 0) {

                tx1.setText("燈泡1:關");
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

For the swipe layout to appear you have to put your views as a child of swipe layout wrapped inside single parent as following:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Other components and views -->

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!-- Child views -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And to change value on refresh you have to set refresh listener as following:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //Do your changes here 
            }
        });
```

Try this out and tell me if any issue.

Comment: i just edited my post, can you please check it one more time? cuz ive already done what you said in your post!! appreciate.

Comment: @吳梓境 Can you please post your updated layout file in your question and please post a better logcat,remove unnecessary things from that? so that i can see what changes you need to make.